# How do I parse XML from a Google App Engine app?

Tags: python, xml, google-app-engine, parsing

How do I parse XML from a Google App Engine app? Any examples?

Answer (score 20):

Since the question was asked, Google has whitelisted pyexpat, which includes minidom, so you can use the following code without having to upload any libraries:

```
from xml.dom import minidom

dom = minidom.parseString('<eg>example text</eg>')
```

More information:
http://docs.python.org/library/xml.dom.minidom.html

Answer (score 8):

Take a look at [existing answers on XML and Python](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=iterparse).

Something like this could work:

```
from cStringIO   import StringIO
from xml.etree   import cElementTree as etree

xml = "<a>aaa<b>bbb</b></a>"

for event, elem in etree.iterparse(StringIO(xml)):
    print elem.text
```

It prints:

```
bbb
aaa
```

Answer (score 4):

AFAIK Google App Engine provides a fairly complete Python environment for you to use. Since Python comes with "batteries included" you may want to evaluate the different APIs which vanilla Python offers you: http://docs.python.org/library/markup.html